# how to get the last items in a row

Tags: c#, .net

I have string like Joe Doe Doe , owner business

and I need to take from this string last name, first name, father name and his position.

```
var str = orgRequ.ValueName.Replace(",", "").Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    string LastName = str.Length > 0 ? str[0] : "";
                    string Name = str.Length > 1 ? str[1] : "";
                    string FatherName = str.Length > 2 ? str[2] : "";
string Positions=string.Join(" ", str.Reverse().Take(str.Count() - 3).ToArray());
```

but ran into a problem that the final position is written as System.Linq.Enumerable +  d__75`1 [System.Char] instead of the owner business. before insert into the database, i need again reverse Positions , how can this be cleaned using best practices

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to specify sample inputs **in the code** and be clear as to the **exact** output you are aiming for.

Comment: Can not reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HgpB2Z

Comment: How do you make people have exactly one Firstname, lastname and father's name?

Comment: [Falsehood programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Your jobtitle is divided from the remaining string by a `,`   - so split the whole string into 2 parts at `','` - take the latter as job title and try to guesstimate the remaining things from the former

Comment: Console.WriteLine(Positions) gives business owner not owner business if i use .Split().Reverse() i see System.Linq.Enumerable+<ReverseIterator>d__75`1[System.String] example https://dotnetfiddle.net/dbSfC3

Comment: @Елена yes because you are doing `str.Reverse()` which changes `{ ..., "owner", "business" }` to `{ "business", "owner", ... }`; if you want the last two elements of str in original order try `str.Skip(str.Count() - 2).ToArray()`

Comment: but if positions have like " president and business owner" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are reversing the `str` in `string Positions` you get `Business Owner` instead of `Owner Business`.

So either you take str[3] + str[4] for a result of Owner Business:
`string Positions = str[3] + " " + str[4];`

Or with your code, you have to `reverse` the two words (attention, quick and dirty):

```
            string Positions = string.Join(" ", str.Reverse().Take(str.Count() - 3).ToArray());

            string output = "";
            string[] splitStrings = Positions.Split(' ');
            for (int i = splitStrings.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                output = output + splitStrings[i] + " ";
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + output); //Owner Business
```